# How to open an image in a new browser tab?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to open an image in new brrowser tab like this:

```
<a href="" target="_blank">
  <img height="660px" width="420px"  
   src="<%= Url.Action("WebPageImage", "WPMManagement", new { id = actualId }) %>" 
   alt="bild mit webseiten version" />
</a>
```

I need to show just an image and nothing else (no styles etc.)
What about href? What do I need in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the href attribute to the URL of your image and you're good to go:

```
<a href='<%= Url.Action("WebPageImage", "WPMManagement", new { id = actualId }) %>' target="_blank">Click here to view the image</a>
```

**EDIT:** If you're retrieving images from the database, then you'll need Url.Action rather than Url.Content. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377801/what-web-control-jquery-should-be-used-to-display-images-from-database/5377959#5377959) for a similar discussion about retrieving images from a database.

**EDIT #2:** Updated the example code to use Url.Action rather than Url.Content

Comment: ho to do that if image is called via actionresult from database?

Comment: That sounds to me like a totally different question than what you originally asked

Comment: i mean which information should i write in Url.Content("")?? I dont have any image on local pc, they all will be loaded from database.

Comment: How is the image stored in the database? is it a file name or path? is it a binary version of the image?

Comment: yes i have a binary version. can i show it in url.content()??

Comment: john-bledsoe: iam using url.action!! see my post under queston. but how can i open image via clicking on it in new tab of browser??

Comment: My last try: I updated the post to use Url.Action rather than Url.Content. I hope that works for you.